# How to Moq Empty or Null Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, autofixture

I am working on xUnit automations for the .NET CORE 5 Web API project. I have response object which got one property as Exception. I am using fixture to create moq data. How I can create empty or null exception using fixture in scenarios where exception doesn't require throw.

At the movement, the fixture create exception which is incorrect for me. I have tried to pass Null but it throw exception

### QueryResponse

```
public class QueryResultSummary
{
    public int RecordsCount { get; set; }
    public bool IsRecordExist { get; set; }
    public bool Error { get; set; }
    public string ExecutionMessage { get; set; }
    public string CustomMessage { get; set; }
    public Exception Exceptions { get; set; }
}
```

### xUnit

```
public async Task APIMethodX_ShouldReturn_DoesNotExist_When_SiteNotFound()
    {
        //Arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        long startDateTimeUtc = 1626994800000;
        int siteId = 5588;

        fixture.Customize<QueryResultSummary>(c => c
           .With(x => x.RecordsCount, 0)
           .With(x => x.IsRecordExist, false)
           .With(x => x.Error, false)
           .With(x => x.ExecutionMessage, QueryExecutionStatusEnum.DoesNotExist.ToString())
           .With(x => x.Exceptions, null) // need help here
       );
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps just `.With(x => x.Exceptions, (Exception)null)`?

Comment: What is `Fixture`? Is that an external library? What is the `x.Exceptions` property? Why do you need to specify it is null? Won't it be null bt default?

Comment: @DavidG It's `AutoFixture`. I've adjusted the tags to include it.

Comment: OK, but what happens if you just remove the entire line? I don't understand why you need to specify that it is null.

Comment: @DavidG AutoFixure creates data for all properties unless you tell it to use something specific, like `null` in this case

Comment: A clearer way would be to use `.Without(x => x.Exceptions)`, both in terms of code and the intent of the test.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that option did worked, also from John .Without(x => x.Exceptions) is very good option to implement as well

Comment: You can use default(type) like below

`fixture.Customize<QueryResultSummary>(c => c
    .With(x => x.Exceptions, default(Exception)));`

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to omit a property, from being populated, while using `Customize` is to define the property using `Without()`.

```cs
fixture.Customize<QueryResultSummary>(c => c
    .Without(x => x.Exceptions));
```

In case you'll need to omit all autoproperties, you can use the `OmitAutoProperties` method.

```cs
fixture.Customize<QueryResultSummary>(c => c
    .OmitAutoProperties());
```